# Using Parameter Passing in Netbeans/Java

Tags: java, netbeans, parameter-passing

I am new to net beans and java and by using net beans GUI, I have to create a linear conversion table. These are the choices:  Inches to Centimeters
Feet to Centimeters
Yards to Meters
Miles to Kilometers. The following formulas can be used to convert English Imperial units of measurements to Metric units:

```
Centimeters = Inches * 2.54    
Centimeters = Feet * 30     
Meters = Yards * 0.91     
Kilometers = Miles * 1.6
```

It should be created using parameter passing and should return values back to method call.`

This is what I have done so far:

```
int conversion;    
double centimetres = 0,value, metres = 0, kilometres = 0;     
conversion=Integer.parseInt(conversioninput.getText());    
value=Integer.parseInt(valueinput.getText());       
if  (conversion==1)      
    centimetres=value*2.54;    
    output.setText(""+value+" inches = "+centimetres+ " centimetres");   
 if (conversion==2)       
     centimetres=value*30;    
     output.setText(""+value+" feet = "+centimetres+ " centimetres");    
 if (conversion==3)    
     metres=value*0.91;    
     output.setText(""+value+" yards = "+metres+ " metres");    
 if (conversion==4)    
     kilometres=value*1.6;    
     output.setText(""+value+" miles = "+kilometres+ " kilometres");
```

I need to include parameter passing and I have no idea how to do it. I am doing an online course and it does not explain anything

Comment: What parameter are you trying to pass? From where and to where?

Comment: I am trying to pass a parameter so I can use 'return' at the end and I want to use it where I have included the if statements. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you would want to do is something like this:

```
public float conversion(int value, int conversion) {
    // put your code inside this method
}
```

Then to call it inside your main method just do:

```
conversion(40, 2);
```

It seems like you are new to programming in general, but I would look into `enums` for the `conversion` variable. And setup a class something like:

```
public enum Conversion { 
    InchToCentimeter, 
    FeetToCentimeter, 
    YardsToMeters, 
    KilometersToMiles 
}
```

Here's a good starting point for enums: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html